# JSON::XS complains if a key is not quoted

Tags: json, perl

I get back JSON in this format:

```
{key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}
```

If I try to use JSON::XS' decode_json method to convert it for me but it's complaining that the keys are not quoted. Is there an option I can set in JSON::XS to ignore this quirk? I looked at the docs but there was nothing obvious.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't quote the keys, it's not valid JSON. A valid JavaScript object is not necessarily a valid JSON object.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/384802).

[JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::PP) has options to allow for more lax parsing of "JSON"-ish input, specifically the [allow_barekey](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON::PP#allow_barekey) option.

Comment: That's my thought. This stupid API claims it is returning JSON.

Comment: You might try JSON::PP, it will have the same error by default but it has additional options.